# I lose my node I2C upon each reboot /dev/i2c-1

Tags: boot-issues, raspi-config

I'm using the last kernel (3.18.7+ #755 PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:14:31 GMT 2015) with the Raspbian :  2015-02-16 on a raspberry rev. B (not +)

My `/boot/config.txt`:

```
dtparam=i2c=on1=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
```

My `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf`:

```
#blacklist spi-bcm2708
#blacklist i2c-bcm2708
blacklist snd-soc-pcm512x
blacklist snd-soc-wm8804
```

Result of some commands after boot:

`lsmod | grep i2c`:

```
i2c_bcm2708             6200  0
```

`dmesg | grep i2c`:

```
[    5.718377] bcm2708_i2c_init_pinmode(1,2)
[    5.754909] bcm2708_i2c_init_pinmode(1,3)
[    5.956520] bcm2708_i2c 20804000.i2c: BSC1 Controller at 0x20804000 (irq 79)
```

`ls /dev/i2c-1`:

```
ls: cannot access /dev/i2c-1: No such file or directory
```

I can create the node without a problem:

```
sudo mknod /dev/i2c-1 c 89 1
```

and after I created this node all work well, but I will lose this dev upon the next reboot, so my question: How I can fix this?

P.S. Works as expected for SPI: both `/dev/spidev0.0` and `/dev/spidev0.1` are created on boot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the line dtparam=i2c=on1=on is a typo.  It should be dtparam=i2c1=on.  You don't need it and the arm line, they are synonyms.

I2C is not like SPI.  The devices /dev/i2c-0 and /dev/i2c-1 are not created by device tree.  I don't know why not.  I guess it's a bug.

Add the following line to /etc/modules

```
i2c-dev
```

That should result in the i2c devices being created during boot.

Comment: thx work for me :)